# Creating a Circle mesh collider for unity using blender

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I'm trying to create a circle mesh collider for unity using blender. This collider should detect raycast. What I did in blender is Add > Mesh > Circle but doesn't work. What am I missing?

Update

```
if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out RaycastHit hit))
{
    Vector2 textureCoord = hit.textureCoord;

    int pixelX = (int)(textureCoord.x * _templateDirtMask.width);
    nt pixelY = (int)(textureCoord.y * _templateDirtMask.height);
}
```

Update 3
[image]

[image]

[image]

Update 4[image]

Comment: The default Blender circle doesn't have a face by default. Did you fill it? Also confirm if you're working with 2d or 3d and show the raycast code as well.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to blender. how can you fill it? I'm working with 2d and I tried it with quad and it's working. I just wanted to create my own mesh collider using blender

Comment: This is going to be a bit of a problem, because meshcolliders are a 3d thing and if you're doing a 2d raycast they simply don't interact. You should reconsider if you really don't want to use [Circle Collider 2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/Manual/class-CircleCollider2D.html) or [Polygon Collider 2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/Manual/class-PolygonCollider2D.html)

Comment: In order to fill the circle in blender select all verts and hit f ;)

Comment: But as said a collider is 3D so a cylinder would actually be more appropriate you would then simply make it have a height of e.g. 0.01 depending on your use case

Comment: @Voidsay I needed meshcolliders cause I'm using raycast for texturecoordinates. Kindly check my updated code above

Comment: @derHugo ok i'll try searching for that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating a circle in Blender make sure to generate one with a face and UVs.

[image: View of the drop down menu to create a circle in Blender]

To do so you must open the drop down window in the bottom left of the screen, select a `Fill Type` (N-Gon or Triangle Fan) and make sure that the `Generate UVs` box is ticked.

Comment: Yes this is what I did. Then in unity I also tick generate colliders

Comment: @Newboy11 did it add a meshcollider component with the correct mesh? Also is the mesh facing towards the camera?

Comment: I think so kindly check the update 3 for confirmation. I don't know how to check if mesh is facing towards camera

Comment: @Newboy11 just checked out your setup. You're indeed running into the issue of backwards facing mesh. The sprite renderer threw me off, since it is rendered double sided, but if you'd quickly switched to mesh render you would see that it is backwards. You have two options either rotate your gameobject 180° or in blender edit mode select the face press `alt` + `n` and select flip before exporting.

Comment: Thank you it's working now just flip Z from blender